# Reading file type (MIME) returns null in Java

Tags: java, file, file-read

I'm editing a custom CSV importer that doesn't want to run on my system.
My version of Java is: "1.8.0_171".

```
String contentType = Files.probeContentType(filePath);          
    //Should return "text/csv";
System.out.println("You have "+contentType+" type file.");
    //returns "You have null type file."
```

I've checked whether the file is accessible - it returns true.

```
System.out.println( "File is readable: " + Files.isReadable(filePath));
// returns: "File is readable: true"
```

What steps should I take next? 
I found some similar bugs:

https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-7144997
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8080369

I don't know whether they are related however.

**UPDATE**
Updating Java to version "10.0.1" did not help.

**UPDATE 2**
Adding null to the list of allowed file types did work, however I consider this a HUGE hack, and this still needs resolving.

Comment: What do your file(names)s look like. If I recall it correctly the default implementation that is shipped with Java on Windows will only try to determine a file's mimetype based on the file suffix. If you want something more sophisticated you might want to try [simplemagic](https://github.com/j256/simplemagic) as suggested in the OpenJDK bug report.

Comment: Javadoc says you get `null` when it did not recognize the file type, but if it was inaccessible you'd probably get an exception. Can you post (the beginning of) the file's content? Worst comes to worst, you could register your own https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType-java.nio.file.Path- FileTypeDetector.

Comment: you could try `FileNameMap` but this only returns limited mime types, such as file is a `.pdf` then it returns `application/pdf`, when the file is `.css` - returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows without any additional `FileTypeDetector` implementations installed Java will use default file type detector `RegistryFileTypeDetector`, which will return whatever has been associated with that extension on that particular machine, meaning whatever is under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.csv` is returned.

If you want to enable some software to run consider installing custom `FileTypeDetector` on classpath via `ServiceLoader` mechanism or associating `.csv` with required value in registry.